How to write a generic, typesafe MongoDB query involving filters?
I'm using the ~latest MongoDB (v6.6.2) in a TypeScript environment.
I have this function:
export async function getCollection<T extends Document>(collection_name: string, skip: number, limit: number, filter: Filter<Document>): Promise<T[]> {
    try {
        let database = await connectToDatabase();
        return database.collection<T>(collection_name).find(filter).skip(skip).limit(limit).toArray();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    }
}


which I invoke like so:
const deviceDBs = await getCollection<DeviceDB>("devices", 0, 0, { location_id: ObjectId.createFromHexString(locationId) });

This code works, but lacks significant typesafety on its filter. I want to generate a TypeScript error if I provide an invalid filter property. location_id is part of the DeviceDB type, but this code continues to compile if I change location_id to foo which is not desirable.
I tried to make this work by changing to filter: Filter<Partial<T>> but that fails to satisfy the type definition for find because it expects to be given T:
find(): FindCursor<WithId<TSchema>>;
find(filter: Filter<TSchema>, options?: FindOptions): FindCursor<WithId<TSchema>>;
find<T extends Document>(filter: Filter<TSchema>, options?: FindOptions): FindCursor<T>;

I found this existing StackOverflow post but it implies things should "just work" when that is not my experience.

Have you tried changing Filter<Document> for Filter<T> in the function argument?

@RemoH.Jansen Yes. If I do that then I am required to pass the full object T in as my filter, but I'm not trying to filter on every property in T. I am trying to filter on a subset of those properties (i.e. just one property in this example)
